# Getting a byte out of a given String of 1s and 0s

Tags: java

I am looking for a fast way to get a byte out of a String, if the string consists of 1s and 0s. For example: String a="101010" . How do I get the Byte b ="101010"?

I looked at some other posts but they usually consist of how to get the byte value of a String. I am interested in basically switching the format.

Edit:
to make it more clear, I am looking for this

```
String a = "101010"
byte b = //What to do?
System.out.print(b)
```

--> 0b101010

Comment: Some more context would be helpful here. Using your examples, why can't you treat `String a` as an array and search if it contains `Byte b` in it. Are you looking for a function that does that?

Comment: Are you looking for `byte b = Byte.parseByte(a, 2);`

Comment: Nope, I have put an extra example to explain what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `byte` is a signed primitive value in Java, when you print it you will get a decimal representation of that value (by default). You need to perform two steps; first, parse the `String` into a `byte`; second, display the `byte` with your desired formatting (as a binary `String` with leading `0b`). That can be done simply enough, something like

```
String a = "101010";
byte b = Byte.parseByte(a, 2);
System.out.printf("0b%s%n", Integer.toBinaryString(b));
```

Which outputs (as requested)

```
0b101010
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Byte` class and other integral types like `Integer` can parse numbers in a range of radices from 2 to 36 (encoded using digits 0-9 and letters A-Z).

```
String a = "101010";
byte b = Byte.parseByte(a, 2);
String c = Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF);
String d = "0b" + c;
```

Remember, a Java `byte` is signed, so we need to mask out any high-order bits that would be introduced when used in a way that promotes the value to a signed `int`.

Comment: String a= "1010";
        byte b = Byte.parseByte(a,2);
        System.out.println(b);

printed the decimal value of a. I want it to print the same as "a" 1010... I am not sure if I am clear enough in my post, I just want to get a byte with the same form.

Comment: @TrickerMacedonia it is not the decimal value that you getting

Comment: @TrickerMacedonia I added some detail about conversion back to a `String`.